# is it possible to to record agora voice call in android studio for and voice call application?

Tags: android-studio, agora.io

I am developing a voice call app on android studio  using agora Api. Now I want to record voice call and  I don't know it is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agora Cloud Recording to record all your voice calls by using simple RESTful APIs. You can have a look at the docs here: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/landing-page?platform=RESTful